# error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onVisited' of undefined in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to log when a user visits faceboook url but I get error when I use onVisited.
This is my background.js

```
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(historyItem){
    if(historyItem.url === "https://www.facebook.com/"){
        console.log('user visits '+historyItem.url+ ' at '+historyItem.lastVisitTime+ ' number of times visited '+historyItem.visitCount);
    }
});
```

I've also added the permission in manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Proj Extension",
  "version": "0.1",

  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"],

    "permissions": ["tabs", "history"]
  },

  "content_scripts":[
    {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
  ]

}
```

Can anybody please suggest why this doesn't work and how else I can do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission key shouldn't be under the background:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Proj Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "history"],
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"],


  },

  "content_scripts":[
    {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
  ]

}
```